# Populate different instances of objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to create several different instances of an 'identity' to use with an API based on a configuration file I have at my application root. The code I am currently using looks like this:

```
public class CloudIdentityProvider : ICloudIdentityProvider
{
    private readonly ISettingsService _settings;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;


    public CloudIdentityProvider(ISettingsService settings)
    {
        this._settings = settings;

    }

    public CloudIdentity GetCloudIdentity(string region)
    { 
            if (region == "LON")
            {
              return new CloudIdentity
              {
                Username = _settings.GetDifferentUsername(),
                APIKey = _settings.GetDifferentKey()
               };
            }


            return new CloudIdentity
            {
                Username = _settings.GetUsername(),
                APIKey = _settings.GetKey()
            };

    }

}
```

I am aware that passing in a string to the method GetCloudIdentity is somewhat brittle. So I was thinking of using an enum... Though I am not sure whether that is even the correct approach here. What is best practice in this situation? What if more regions are added, I dont want to have to keep amending different files

Comment: Amended, forgot a few bits...

Comment: If you have multiple decent values for your `region` that will change only rarely you may use an `enum`. If the values change often you´re better off using a string, so that you don´t have to re-build the entire data-layer also.

Comment: Looks a bit like you are looking for a factory pattern instead

Comment: @Icepickle I wondered about that. So essentially I would just be comparing the `region` to other regions and returning them. For example if (region == "some-region") return new SomeRegion ... ?

Comment: but doing that for each region seems kind of irritating. I guess I will have to resort to doing that if there is no other way

Comment: well yeah, depends on how you want to do it, you might as well fill a dictionary with a string to identity when constructing the object, and simply return the matching item from the dictionary, if not the default identity. If you have like 200 regions then it would be clearly not the correct way, but that's hard to say from what you are suggesting